# Modern Combat Sandstorm Texture problem on Acer Liquid Metal

Tags: applications, compatibility

The game works perfectly except many graphical glitches with textures (mainly those in the background).
any hints?

I have Acer Liquid Metal, official Froyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [contact GameLoft](http://www.gameloft.com/index.php?platform=gameloft&section=home).  They officially support the Acer Liquid for that game, and thus should be able to help you (or at least take a bug report).  They don't specify which versions of the Liquid they support, so it could just be that they haven't tested on the Metal.